# Problem accessing a unique local address on IPv6

Tags: ipv6

I'm quite new to the IPv6 world.

I'm trying to ping the address `fc00::a6:32:67:c9:23` from another host on the same network but it doesn't work so far (although I am able to ping the device with the Link-Local unicast address).

The network configuration on my local host (the source of the ping) looks like this:

```
host1$ ip addr
2: wlp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:4a:7d:cd:e6:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.55.61/24 brd 192.168.55.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp6s0
       valid_lft 348sec preferred_lft 348sec
    inet6 fe80::68b0:2809:2bab:2e8b/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: enx000ec6a6aea4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0e:c6:a6:ae:a4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.55.198/24 metric 1024 brd 192.168.55.255 scope global dynamic enx000ec6a6aea4
       valid_lft 599sec preferred_lft 599sec
    inet6 fc00::e:c6a6:aea4/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2576:c20e:e91d:7677/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The local routing table looks like:

```
$ ip -6 route
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2001:db8:100:1ff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev enx000ec6a6aea4 proto static metric 1024 pref medium
fc00::/64 dev enx000ec6a6aea4 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlp6s0 proto kernel metric 1024 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enx000ec6a6aea4 proto kernel metric 1024 pref medium
default via 2001:db8:100:1ff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev enx000ec6a6aea4 proto static metric 1024 pref medium
```

The interface on the target host looks like this:

```
host2$ ip a
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:67:c9:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.55.187/24 brd 192.168.55.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 599sec preferred_lft 524sec
    inet6 fc00::a6:32:67:c9:23/64 scope global tentative noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2001::a6:32:67:c9:23/64 scope global noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a790:54e2:224b:f14/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I was wondering why is there a `tentative` next to my `fc00`-prefixed IP address on the target host?

Does anyone knows ? Is it the cause of my pinging problem ?

Comment: What address are you trying to ping? What does "it doesn't work so far" mean...are you getting errors? Some other unexpected behavior? What do your ipv6 routes look like (`ip -6 route`)? Are you trying to ping *to* the raspberry pi or *from* the raspberry pi? What does the network configuration on the *other* device look like?

Comment: I'm trying to ping to "fc00::a6:32:67:c9:23". On the other machine, I get "Address unreachable". On the other machine, `ip -6 route` gives three lines: one for `::1`, two for `fe80::`. I tried to ping to the RPi. The network configuration on the other machine has the entry :
    inet6 fc00::e:c6a6:aea4/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: It would be great if you could update your question with that information, and include the actual output of `ip -6 route`, `ip addr`, etc on the remote machine (because that's easier to understand than the prose description).

Comment: @larsks I updated the question with the information you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your source host has:

```
inet6 fc00::e:c6a6:aea4/64 scope global
```

The output of `ip -6 route` shows no route to the corresponding network, nor does it show a default ipv6 route. Your source host doesn't know how to reach the target address.

If I assign that address on a local system, it automatically generates an appropriate route:

```
host1$ ip addr add fc00::e:c6a6:aea4/64 dev eth0
host1$ ip -6 route
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fc00::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium   # <-- this one here
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 1024 pref medium
```

But there's a second problem: The address `fc00::e:c6a6:aea4/64` is on network `fc00::/64`. However, your target address, `fc00::a6:32:67:c9:23/64`, is on network `fc00:0:0:a6::/64`. That means even if you have the automatically generated route on `host1`, it's still not going to be able to reach your target address on `host2`.

To get this to work in my test setup, I needed to add routes on both systems.

1. On `host1`, I need to add a route to `fc00:0:0:a6::/64`:

```
host1$ ip route add fc00:0:0:a6::/64 dev eth0
```

2. On `host2`, I need to add a route to `fc00::/64`:

```
host2$ ip route add fc00::/64 dev wlan0
```

With these changes in place I can successfully ping `fc00::a6:32:67:c9:23` from `fc00::e:c6a6:aea4`:

```
[root@host1 ~]# ip -6 addr show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    altname eno2
    altname enp0s31f6
    inet6 fc00::e:c6a6:aea4/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ed9c:756f:92a:ef21/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

[root@host1 ~]# ip -6 route | grep -v fe80
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fc00::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fc00:0:0:a6::/64 dev eth0 metric 1024 pref medium

[root@host1 ~]# ping -c2 fc00::a6:32:67:c9:23
PING fc00::a6:32:67:c9:23(fc00::a6:32:67:c9:23) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fc00::a6:32:67:c9:23: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=107 ms
64 bytes from fc00::a6:32:67:c9:23: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=15.3 ms

--- fc00::a6:32:67:c9:23 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 15.287/61.178/107.070/45.891 ms
```

Comment: Sorry, the ouput of `ip -6 route` was wrong, I edited it. Don't look at the `2001::...` address, this address is a dummy one.

Comment: This answer is still accurate: your two IPv6 addresses are on different networks and you need to add explicit routes for this to work.

Comment: Is it a valid solution to change the IP from `fc00::a6:32:67:c9:23` to `fc00::32:67:c9:23` then ?

Comment: Sure, that puts the two addresses on the same network so that no additional routes will be necessary.

Comment: The IPv6 in the RPi was set with `slaac hwaddr` in /etc/dhcpcd.conf so I changed the IP on the other device from `fc00::e:c6a6:aea4` to `fc00::a6:0:e:c6a6:aea4` and it works ! Thank you.

Comment: If this answer helped you out, consider marking it "accepted" by checking the checkmark to the left of the question.